# Sending UDPv6 locally in golang

Tags: go, udp, ipv6

I need to send a UDPv6 datagram being able to track this message by a local receiver (or via `tcpdump`).

```
daddr, err = net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp6", "[address]:port")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp6", nil, daddr)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer conn.Close()

conn.Write(...)
```

Unlike IPv4 this code doesn't work with IPv6. For example, when I try to send a datagram to a multicast address, e.g. to [FF01::DB8:0:0]:5000, I get `connect: invalid argument`. The same happens when I try to send it to [fe80::20c:29ff:fee1:d66]:5000 (my IPv6 address according to `ifconfig`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases (link-local and interface-local multicast) you have forgotten to specify the scope ID. Without this, it is impossible to determine which interface to use, and you get an `Invalid argument` error from the operating system.

[`net.UDPAddr`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPAddr) uses the `Zone` field to store the scope ID. You need to ensure that you have provided one, either by setting `Zone` explicitly or by using the [percent-suffix notation](https://superuser.com/q/99746/144961).

Comment: Thanks! For my card address I get `write: connection refused`, for a (link-local) multicast address it works as expected.